What start script can i use on this discord bot to start a 1.18.2 forge server?
First off i am no expert in this field, i have made well over 20 minecraft server but that bot is flippin me off.(link to github: https://github.com/iy4vet/minecraft-server-discord-bot-python)
I am trying to find a start script for starting a server, but because the forge server installer has a run.bat ready, that says:
java @user_jvm_args.txt @libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.18.2-40.2.4/win_args.txt %* pause
I don't have a specific file (like a jar, like in fabric modpacks) to start trought a .bat. (the server starts trough this file without a problem)
The start script will be pasted in an bot.env file
I tried to copy past the entire thing, i tried the usual java -Xmx20G -jar server.jar 
I pasted the entire code asked Chatgpt but no luck yet
